# Force.com site showing no data

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I am farily new to visualforce pages and even newer to force.com sites.  I built a simple visualforce page that lists every record on a custom object.  Viewing the apex page, I can see all the data.  I then tried to create a public force.com site using this visual force page and the all I get is a blank page.  I checked the public access settings and have given view all rights to custom object.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<apex:page standardController="Deny_IP__c" recordSetVar="DenyIP" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!DenyIP}" var="d">
      <apex:column value="{!d.IP__c}"/>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Did you check CRUD and FLS on the Deny_IP__c object for the guest user (Public Settings) as well?

Answer (score 4):

1. Check in the public access if you've granted the access to that VF Page.
2. Add `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag, maybe you will see some errors.
3. Finally - enable debug logs on Mr. "{site name} Guest User" and try viewing it? "preview as admin" is worth trying out too.